# Cant get artists in my asp mvc site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello im trying to make a music app for sharing music, but i have the following problem. [Look red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nCRT.png)

Where i placed the red circle i want to load the artist i made in my class. I tried with an dictionary but wont work the extension `PagedList`.

The view off the webpage above looks like the following:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<table class="table">

    @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Song>) ViewData["songs"])
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="artist">Artiest</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="playbtn btn btn-sm btn-default btn-circle pull-right" data-item="@item.Mp3File"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-plus favoritebutton pull-right">Add to favorites</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

And the controller of the song looks the following:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, int pagesize = 8)
    {
            List<Artist> artists = artistRepository.GetArtistBySongID(int id);
            List<Song> songs = songRepository.ReadSongs();
            List<Song> recommended = songRepository.GetFavoritesById(Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]));
            ViewData["recommended"] = recommended;
            PagedList<Song> pagedList = new PagedList<Song>(songs, page, pagesize);
            ViewData["songs"] = pagedList;  
            return View();  
    }
```

My song class looks the following:

```
public class Song
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private string genre;
    private DateTime release_date;
    private string mp3file;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Genre
    {
        get { return genre; }
        set { genre = value; }
    }

    public DateTime ReleaseDate
    {
        get { return release_date; }
        set { release_date = value; }
    }

    public string Mp3File
    {
        get { return mp3file; }
        set { mp3file = value; }
    }

    public Song(string name, string genre, DateTime release_date, string mp3file)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.release_date = release_date;
        this.mp3file = mp3file;
    }

    public Song(int id, string name, string genre, DateTime release_date, string mp3file)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.release_date = release_date;
        this.mp3file = mp3file;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", Id, Name, Genre, ReleaseDate, mp3file);
    }
```

Comment: `.GetArtistBySongID(int id);` - this won't compile?? Where's `id` coming from?

Comment: Thats what i need to know. How can i get the id from the html page?

Comment: What does `Song` look like? Can you edit your question to show the code of the `Song` class

Comment: Looks like you have a modelling problem - Why do you need a separate `GetArtistBySongID` - I feel there should be an `Artist` property on `Song`

Comment: Do i need to create a modelview for this? In what way can i use that, can u send me a example?

Comment: This is way too broad, we're not here to write code for you

Answer (score 0):

> > List artists = artistRepository.GetArtistBySongID(int id);

This is your first problem. You want a list of artists -- each corresponding to a song, but you are only giving it the id of one song.  That going to return one artist, not a list.   So, you need to go through you list of song, pull out the id, get the artist for that song, and build a list.

```
List<Artist> artists = new List<Artist>();
List<Song> songs = songRepository.ReadSongs();

PagedList<Song> pagedList = new PagedList<Song>(songs, page, pagesize); 
foreach(var song in pagedList)
      artists.Add(artistRepository.GetArtistBySongID(song.ID));

ViewData["songs"] = pagedList; 
ViewData["artists"] = artists;
```

But, this only solved part of your problem, because now in the View, we have to step through the artist list at the same time as we're stepping through the song list.

I think the easiest solution would be to add a `Artist` property to the `Song` object, but that may cause it own problems.  (But, try it first before moving on).

If you can't add the property to the SOng object, next best would be to make a Tuple.

```
List<Song> songs = songRepository.ReadSongs();

PagedList<Song> pagedList = new PagedList<Song>(songs, page, pagesize); 
var songartists = new List<Tuple<Song, Artist>> 

foreach(var song in pagedList)
      songartists .Add(Tuple.Creeate(song, artistRepository.GetArtistBySongID(song.ID)));

ViewData["songs"] = songartists ;
```

Then in you View change

```
@foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Song>) ViewData["songs"])
{
```

to:

```
@foreach (var song in (IEnumerable<Tuple<Song, Artist>) ViewData["songs"])
{
    var item = song.Item1;
    var artist = song.Item2;
```